# Get pip to work with git and github repository

Tags: python, django, git, github, pip

I'm writting a python app that depends on another one that is hosted on a github repository (never in pypi) for development reasons.

Lets call them:

- App being written: `AppA`
- App in github: `AppB`

In App A, the setup.py is like:

```
# coding=utf-8
import sys
try:
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
except ImportError:
    import distribute_setup
    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        # other requirements that install correctly
        'app_b==0.1.1'
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'git+https://github.com/user/app_b.git@0.1.1#egg=app_b-0.1.1'
    ]
)
```

Now `AppA` is being built by `Jenkins CI` with every push and I get a failure because of the next error is thrown:

```
error: Download error for git+https://github.com/user/app_b.git@0.1.1: unknown url type: git+https
```

Funny thing is that this only happens in Jenkins, it works perfectly on my computer. I tried both of the other SSH urls that github gives and those are not even considered for download.

Now, AppA is included in the requirements file of a project also being built by Jenkins, so installing the dependencies manually via `pip install AppA` `pip install AppB` is not an option, the dependencies are automatically installed by being included in the `requirements.txt`.

Is there any way to make pip and git with github urls work together?

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure Jenkins uses pip? If yes, is it a version that supports this feature?

Comment: @Gerard what version of pip does your Jenkins box use?  `pip --version` should give you that information.  Off the cuff, it looks like pre-0.8.2, which did not support the https scheme.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is not with `pip`, is with `setuptools`. The responsible for the `setup()` call is `setuptools` package (setuptools or distribute project).

Neither `setuptools` or `distribute` understand that kind of url, they understand tarballs/zip files.

Try pointing to Github's download url - usually a zip file.

Your `dependency_links` entry is probably going to look like:

```
dependency_links=[
    'https://github.com/user/app_b/archive/0.1.1.zip#egg=app_b-0.1.1'
]
```

For more information take a look at http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi

Comment: In addition to this answer, in my case the package could never be installed if such package within `requires` was in the form `package==version`, but it worked using `package`; that is, only the package name without version

Comment: how could you add a private repository's branch as a dependency link? This is after all one of the main reasons to use git+[https|ssh] style requirements

Answer (score 2):

From [pip documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html#git) -

```
pip currently supports cloning over git, git+http and git+ssh:

git+git://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
git+http://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
git+ssh://git.myproject.org/MyProject#egg=MyProject
```

Try replacing `git+https` with `git+git`.

Comment: Sorry this didn't work. It works locally but not within Jenkins :( I'm trying to figure something out. thanks anyway

Comment: `git+https` should be supported, despite the documentation.  At least according to the [source](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/vcs/git.py#L17).  That appeared all the way back in pip 0.8.2.

Comment: I'm just saying what the error is showing - `unknown url type: git+https`. Must be some old version of pip.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in 2019, but due to different reasons. *dependency_links* are not supported in pip anymore (tested with pip>=20.0.0). For my case I solved this issue using *install_requirements* and defining a direct reference (see pip manual *direct reference*).

```
...
install_requirements = [
    <dependencyname> @ git+<url of dependency repository>@<branchname or tag>
]
```

I made an puplic example repository named *thepackage* at https://gitlab.rhrk.uni-kl.de/scheliga/thepackage for more details.