# Install transitive bitbucket dependencies via pip

Tags: python, dependencies, pip, setuptools

The situation I'm trying to resolve is installing a package from a private repository on bitbucket which has it's own dependency on another private repository in bitbucket.

I use this to kick off the install:

```
pip install -e git+https://bitbucket.org/myuser/project-one.git/master#egg=django_one
```

which then attempts to download it's dependencies from setup.py that look like:

```
install_requires = ['project-two',],
dependency_links = ['git+https://bitbucket.org/myuser/project-two.git/master#egg=project_two'],
```

This fails, the pip log looks like:

```
Downloading/unpacking project-two (from project-one)

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/project-two/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/project-two/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (project-two does not have any releases)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/project-two/ when looking for download links for project-two (from project-one)
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for project-two (from project-one):
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/project-two/
  * git+https://bitbucket.org/myuser/project-two.git/master#egg=project-two
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/project-two/
  Cannot look at git URL git+https://bitbucket.org/myuser/project-two.git/master#egg=project-two
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/project-two/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (project-two does not have any releases)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/project-two/ when looking for download links for project-two (from project-one)
  Skipping link git+https://bitbucket.org/myuser/project-two.git/master#egg=project-two; wrong project name (not project-two)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement project-two (from project-one)
```

The curious thing about this setup is, if I take a clone of project-one and run

```
python setup install
```

from there, project-two is fetched from bitbucket and installed into my virtualenv. My understanding was that pip was using setup tools under the hood, so my assumption was the success of that test validated my approach.

Any suggestions appreciated.

**FOLLOW UP:**

So the accepted answer is quite right - but my problem had the additional complexity of being a private repo (https + http auth-basic). Using the syntax

```
dependency_links=["http://user:password@bitbucket.org/myuser/..."]
```

still caused a 401. Running up a shell and using `pip.download.py` to run `urlopen` demonstrates the underlying problem (ie pip needs additional setup in `urllib2` to get this working).

The problem is mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/786) but I couldn't get that working.

Comment: are you sure than the repo on bitbubket is a git repo? bitbucket supports also mecurial.

Comment: @markdsievers Did you find any solution? I'm looking for too!

Comment: Assembla has upgrading issues with pip in this type of scenario, not sure if it's directly related but this question and answer does help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip` created the idea of a VCS installation, so you can use `git+https://path/to/repo.git`, but `setuptools` does not understand that.

When you create a `setup.py` file you are using only `setuptools` (no `pip` involved), and `setuptools` does not understand that kind of URL.

You can use `dependency_links` with tarballs or zip files, but not with git repositories.

Replace your `depencency_links` by:

```
dependency_links=["https://bitbucket.org/myuser/project-two/get/master.zip#egg=project-two"]
```

And check if it works.

There is a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14928126/565999

---

### References:

- http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't end up getting this resolved because of the private/auth repo issue mentioned - but your info was quite correct and got my on the right path. So thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm stuck at this point too.  Mark, were you ever able to figure out a way to avoid this 401 error?  I've tried basic auth and I'm completely at a loss as to why it doesn't seem to recognize the user credentials that I provide.