# How to `pip install` a package that has Git dependencies?

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a private library called `some-library` *(actual names have been changed)* with a setup file looking somewhat like this:

```
setup(
    name='some-library',

    // Omitted some less important stuff here...

    install_requires=[
        'some-git-dependency',
        'another-git-dependency',
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/some-git-dependency.git#egg=some-git-dependency',
        'git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/another-git-dependency.git#egg=another-git-dependency',
    ],
)
```

All of these Git dependencies *may* be private, so [installation via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14928126/4101697) is not an option. I can use `python setup.py install` and `python setup.py develop` in `some-library`'s root directory without problems.

However, installing over Git doesn't work:

```
pip install -vvv -e 'git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/some-library.git@1.4.4#egg=some-library'
```

The command fails when it looks for `some-git-dependency`, mistakenly assumes it needs to get the dependency from PyPI and then fails after concluding it's not on PyPI. My first guess was to try re-running the command with `--process-dependency-links`, but then this happened:

```
   Cannot look at git URL git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/some-git-dependency.git#egg=some-git-dependency
   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement some-git-dependency (from some-library) (from versions: )
```

Why is it producing this vague error? What's the proper way to `pip install` a package with Git dependencies that might be private?

Comment: did you try `--process-dependency-links --allow-all-external`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the proper way to pip install a package with Git dependencies that might be private?

Two options

1. Use `dependency_links` as you do. See below for details.
2. Along side the `dependency_links` in your setup.py's, use a special `dependency-links.txt` that collects all the required packages. Then add this package in requirements.txt. That's my recommendend option as explained below.

   ```
   # dependency-links.txt
   git+ssh://...@tag#egg=package-name1
   git+ssh://...@tag#egg=package-name2
   # requirements.txt (per deployed application)
   -r dependency-links.txt
   ```

While option 2 adds some extra burden on package management, namely keeping dependency-links.txt up to date, it makes installing packages a lot easier because you can' forget to add the `--process-dependency-link` option on `pip install`.

Perhaps more importantly, using dependency-links.txt you get to specify the exact version to be installed on deployment, which is want you want in a CI/CD environment - nothing is more risky than to install *some* version. From a package maintainer's perspective however it is common and considered good practice to specify a minimum version, such as

```
    # setup.py in a package
    ...
       install_requires = [ 'foo>1.0', ... ]
```

That's great because it makes your packages work nicely with other packages that have similar dependencies yet possibly on different versions. However, in a deployed application this can still cause mayhem if there are conflicting requirements among packages. E.g. package A is ok with `foo>1.0`, package B wants `foo<=1.5` and the most recent version is `foo==2.0`. Using dependency-links.txt you can be specific, applying one version for all packages:

```
    # dependency-links.txt
    foo==1.5
```

> The command fails when it looks for some-git-dependency,

To make it work, you need to add [--process-dependency-links](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/?highlight=process-dependency-links#cmdoption--process-dependency-links) for pip to recognize the dependency to github, e.g.

```
pip install --process-dependency-links -r private-requirements.txt
```

Note since [pip 8.1.0](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#release-notes) you can add this option to requirements.txt. On the downside it gets applied to *all* packages installed and may have unintended consequences. That said, I find using `dependency-links.txt` is a safer and more manageable solution.

> All of these Git dependencies may be private

There are three options:

1. Add collaborators on each of the required packages' repositories. These collaborators need to have their ssh keys setup with github for this to work. Then use `git+ssh://...`
2. Add a deploy key to each of the repositories. The downside here is that you need to distribute the corresponding private key to all the machines that need to deploy. Again use `git+ssh://...`
3. Add a personal access token on the github account that holds the private repositories. Then you can use `git+https://accesstoken@github.com/...` The downside is that the access token will have read + write access to all repositories, public and private, on the respective github account. On the plus side distributing and managing per-repository private keys is no longer necessary, and cycling the key is a lot simpler. In an all-inhouse environment where every dev has access to all repositories I have found this to be the most efficient, hassle-free way for everybody. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation!

Comment: does this mean `pip` cannot process `dependency_links` without a requirements.txt? if yes, is `pip` incompatible with `setuptools`? OP said `easy_install` does, `pip` does not.

Comment: @NizamMohamed   you can `pip install --process-dependency-links whatever-package` and it will work fine. pip's primary purpose is to install from the official pypi repository and so by default does not process dependency links.

Comment: Outdated. Does not work anymore. `--process-dependency-links` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for private repositories as well:

```
dependency_links = [
     'git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/some-git-dependency.git@master#egg=some-git-dependency',
     'git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/another-git-dependency.git@master#egg=another-git-dependency'
],
```

Comment: Explicitly adding `@master` did not do the trick for me. Looking at the verbose log, there's not even a mention of the Git repository now. Only this: `Collecting some-git-dependency (from some-library)
  1 location(s) to search for versions of some-git-dependency:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/some-git-dependency/`

I'm on pip 8.1.1 and setuptools 20.10.1.

Answer (score 1):

You should use git+git when url with #egg, like this:

```
-e git+git@repo.some.la:foo/my-repo.git#egg=my-repo
```

Use git+ssh in production without #egg, but you can specify @version or branch @master

```
git+ssh://git@repo.some.la/foo/my-repo.git@1.1.6
```

for work with app versions use git tagging [Git Basics - Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

Comment: This didn't work for me. Also, I don't want to install these dependencies in editable mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I refer to "[pip install dependency links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26062864/6309)", you would not refer to the GitHub repo itself, but to the tarball image associated to that GitHub repo:

```
dependency_links=[
        'git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/some-git-dependency/tarball/master/#egg=some-git-dependency',
        'git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/another-git-dependency/tarball/master/#egg=another-git-dependency',
    ],
```

with "`some-git-dependency`" being the name *and version of the dependency.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work over SSH, only HTTP(S). It needs to work over SSH because the repos may be private and I want to authenticate using SSH keys. Can you provide a working example over SSH?

Answer (score 0):

*"Cannot look at git URL git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/some-git-dependency.git#egg=some-git-dependency"* means `pip` cannot fetch an html page from this url to look for direct download links in the page, i.e, `pip` doesn't recognize the URL as a vcs checkout, because maybe some discrepancy between the requirement specifier and the fragment part in the vcs url.

> In the case of a VCS checkout, you should also append `#egg=project-version` in order to identify for what package that checkout should be used.
>
> Be sure to escape any dashes in the name or version by replacing them with underscores.

Check [Dependencies that aren’t in PyPI](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi)

**replace `-` with an `_` in the package and version string**.

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/my-organization/some-git-dependency.git#egg=some_git_dependency
```

and `--allow-all-external` may be useful.